# Open large files with R

Tags: r, memory, file-io, memory-management

I want to process a file (1.9GB) that contains 100.000.000 datasets in R.
Actually I only want to have every 1000th dataset.
Each dataset contains 3 Columns, separated by a tab.
I tried: data <- read.delim("file.txt"), but R Was not able to manage all datasets at once.
Can I tell R directly to load only every 1000th dataset from the file?

After reading the file I want to bin the data of column 2.
Is it possible to directly bin the number written in column 2?
Is it possible the read the file line by line, without loading the whole file into the memory?

Thanks for your help.

Sven

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should pre-process the file using another tool before reading into R.

To write every 1000th line to a new file, you can use [sed](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq.html), like this:

```
sed -n '0~1000p' infile > outfile
```

Then read the new file into R:

```
datasets <- read.table("outfile", sep = "\t", header = F)
```

Comment: After installing gsed on MacOSX you can use the sed-command directly in R: `read.delim(pipe("/opt/local/bin/gsed -n '1~1000p' data.txt"), header=FALSE)`. On Linux (which already has gnu sed installed) it is as always easier: just use `read.delim(pipe("sed -n '1~1000p' data.txt"), header=FALSE)`. Keep in mind that the line-numbering starts with 1 and not with 0.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to look at the *manual* devoted to [R Data Import/Export](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html).

Naive approaches always load all the data. You don't want that.  You may want another script which reads line-by-line (written in awk, perl, python, C, ...) and emits only every N-th line.  You can then read the output from that program directly in R via a pipe -- see the help on Connections.

In general, very large memory setups require some understanding of R.  Be patient, you will get this to work but once again, a naive approach requires lots of RAM and a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: +1 for suggestion to read the manual (and giving a link).  High Performance task view  http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html may also be useful ...

Comment: @Dirk do the `nrows` and `skip` arguments to `read.table` not affect how much of the file is loaded?

Comment: Not for interleaving: `skip` rows can be omitted at the start, `nrows` total rows can be read.  That is different from reading every third row.

Comment: I just want to make sure that R does not provide a way to read a file line by line. Is it only possible to read the whole file or nothing? There could be something like

while ((line <- readLine("file.dat")) != NULL) {
    # done something with the line, e.g. extract data
}

Comment: If you want to read line by line, you can --- see the aforementioned manual. But convenience functions like `read.table()` and its cousins `read.csv()` etc read the *whole* file (modulo arguments `skip` and `nrows` as mentioned earlier).

Comment: I had a look at http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html but I could not find anything about how I can read one line after another and having only the one line in the memory -- (as I tried to indicate it with the code in my previous comment).

Using read.table with nrows and skip would mean that I have to open the file 100'000'000 times (in the worst case) and I want to avoid that :-D

Comment: See `help(readLines)`; you want `n=1`.  And this will be *very slow* for a large file, hence my initial hint at `sed`, `awk`, ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe package [colbycol](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colbycol/index.html) could be usefull to you.

Comment: I'd like to have a "rowbyrow". A method/function delivers one line after the next one to a variable and keeps only that line in the memory.

For Example Lie this: **while ((line <- readLine("file.dat")) != NULL) { # do something with the line, e.g. extract data }**